# how to get font from the previous activity on current activity on canvas

Tags: android

how to get  font from the previous activity on current activity on canvas

Answer (score 1):

You can pass information from one activity to the next using the extras in the intent used to start the 2nd activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...)
intent.putExtra("font", myFont);
```

Then in onCreate for the 2nd activity

```
Font myFont = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("font");
```

Comment: No problem.  If this works for you, you can mark it as the answer by hitting the checkbox on the left.